# C# SQL Server database queries

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have written the following code to query stuff from a SQL Server database. The query in the first reader works, but not in the second. I just can't seem to figure out why as the approach is exactly the same in both readers. Any help is much appreciated.

The parameters for the commands are given in the function above which isn't in the code btw.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    conn.ConnectionString = "...";
    conn.Open();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT stuff FROM table WHERE Belegnummer= @n and Belegjahr=@j", conn);

    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("n", nr));
    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("j", jahr));

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            r = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }

    command.Dispose();

    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT stuff1, stuff2, stuff3 FROM sameTable WHERE BelID = @rnr", conn);
    command2.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("rnr", r));

    using (SqlDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader2.Read()) 
        {
             // variables are defined somewhere above
             b = reader2.GetInt32(0);
             j = reader2.GetInt32(1);
             m = reader2.GetInt32(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: Also define "doesn't work" - what are you expecting the result to be, and how is what you're getting different?

Comment: What doesn't  work out?

Comment: Could it be simply that you don't have any record that matches your WHERE condition in the second command?

Comment: what is the oputput of  reader2.Read() and then decide .GetInt32(0)

Comment: it seems that your second sql command will run with the parameter `r` obtained by the last iteration in the first sql command. Is that really what you want ? And, as someone else already asked, can you check the value and the expected result with this value ?

Comment: ok nevermind it was just the stupid type conversion.

Comment: sorry for the question^^

Comment: was literally trying for 1 hour to solve this and 5 min after posting here i found the error^^

Comment: @Alex. If the question is of no importance for future readers then it is best to just remove it

Answer (score 1):

Please post the error messages as well.

You may run into trouble with DbNull values. Check for DbNull before you parse the values with:

```
SqlReader.IsDBNull(column)
```

Or load the Data into a DataTable:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```